# "Web console is activated in the test environment" when testing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie to Rails. Therefore, apologies in advance if this is a dumb question. I have gone through Michael Heartl's book and tried coding an app myself.

I have written a few basic tests, but when trying to test the app with

$bundle exec rake test

I get the following message on the terminal

```
Web Console is activated in the test environment, which is
usually a mistake. To ensure it's only activated in development
mode, move it to the development group of your Gemfile:

    gem 'web-console', group: :development

If you still want to run it the test environment (and know
what you are doing), put this in your Rails application
configuration:

    config.web_console.development_only = false
```

When I add the above to development.rb it still doesn't make a difference.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Update - I added 

config.web_console.development_only = false

to the config/application.rb within the class Application < Rails::Application

which allowed me to run the tests.

But I still need to know if this method is correct when running tests or is there a better way

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What rails and ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need to do is make sure that in your Gemfile the line `gem 'web-console'` is only loaded in the group development.

Can you maybe post your Gemfile? This way we can see if that is what's causing it.

In your Gemfile it should either be:

```
gem 'web-console', group: :development
```

or

```
group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. My gem file looks like this:

group :development, :test do
  
  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

Comment: I mimicked what you have given above and i removed the ':test' attribute from the group function. This worked. now I'm not getting the error. I'm very curious as to what the reason must have been, and why Rails 2.0 generates the gemfile like so by default.

Answer (score 1):

In the Gem file if you have this line

```
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
```

Remove it.

Then run

```
$ gem install bundler

$ bundle install --without production
```

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through Michael Hartl's course as well. I know the Gemfile states that you should have it the way you have it but it brings up that message. If you don't want to change the Gemfile and leave it as the way in the book, you can go to config > environments > test.rb and add in the line below.

```
config.web_console.development_only = false
```

Save this and you're good to go.